# Is it reasonable a remote control works after being heated?

Tags: heat, remote-control, humidity

The remote control of my TV set is failing and I probably have to buy a new one soon. I changed battery, including from other device that is working, and there was no improvement.

But it is interesting that sometimes it works properly, and sometimes doesn't work at all.

It seems related to sunny days (works) and rainy days (not work), while the correlation is not 100%;

My question is about what I tried several times with good results when it is not working: put it (after removing batteries) inside a turned off furnace, still with a residual heat and a temperature of 35 - 45 C I guess. Until now it always starts to work.

Comment: That’s hot, but what failure symptoms and model? Is it dusty inside?..

Comment: As i said, sometimes nothing works. Sometimes (as now) the volume control only increases and doesn't decreases. It is a Sony RM-YD092.

Comment: Is it the remote that fails or ?

Comment: If you have a crack in a track by the pad, or a dry soldered joint to the pad, a small temperature change, via thermal expansion, can make or break the connection. This may seem unlikely, I would expect a very small fraction of devices to have this problem, one in a billion maybe at a pidooma. But in devices which have a temperature-related intermittent? The proportion of those would be much much higher. It's happened to me, and it was a pain to find. Flexing the board, poking the board with a plastic stick, and directed spraying of freezer can all help to provoke/isolate this type of problem.

Comment: If ambient is 45’C and TV consumes 85W, the power supply may be over 85’C which some caps are limited to rapid aging. Others are rated to 105’C but this still is rapid aging.  If power fails weird things can happen.   If dusty, creapage leakage on high V input to supply may induce failure. be sure Remote batteries are fresh. Humidity increases risk of creapage / leakage with dust inside and vacuum cleaning may help with power disconnected. Any bulged large E-caps must be replaced (cheap)

Comment: Where do you live in 45’C with no ACU? Abadan or Adelaide or Death Valley or In. .

Comment: I have to clarify: the ambient temperature is 20-30 C. 35-45 is the temperature of the furnace where I put the device to "fix" it temporarilly.

Comment: If you have trouble with an exact replacement 1. Universal remotes cover many but notr all sets. 2. Learning remotes can be programmed by the IR output of your old remote (when it works)

Comment: It is working good in the last week. It may be a problem of low isolation due to wet wheater.

Answer (score 0):

Most remotes fail because the elastomeric switches wear out.

Did you notice if any of the buttons were more problematic than others ? Heat may release some conducting chemicals from the elastomer but it's a fairly futile task.

If you have the skill and time, many remotes can have their switches 'repaired'. Some googling is required for the method and ebay has the materials.

Another suggestion is to buy a 'universal' remote.